# JavaScript - Remove Minecraft Color Codes from String

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to remove minecraft color codes from a string:

```
[§aAnnouncement§r] §4test
```

and I searched here, tried my own, to no avail.

Code:

```
module.exports.regexTest = function (message) {
    var regex = '(?i)§[0-9A-FK-OR]/g';
    return message.replace(regex,'');
};
```

Now, by all accounts everything tells me that that regular expression works, but when I parse the message in post it doesn't remove anything.

What is wrong with this regex code?

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @anubhava for his help. It turns out the source I was recieving from was sending the wrong unicode. Fixed code:

```
console.log(message.replace(/\u00A7[0-9A-FK-OR]/ig,''));
```

Thanks for all your help, everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(?i)` is not supported in Javascript regex, try this regex:

```
var regex = /\u00A7[0-9A-FK-OR]/ig;
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/sE3jK9/2)

Comment: What was the problem besides it not being a string and (?i)? Like is there a difference between all the languages?

Comment: I had to deselect this as the answer, neither of the answers have worked after trying them. I got a little excited. Sorry about that.

Comment: The demo works, the program itself still doesn't replace the characters being sent at it. `return message.replace(/§[0-9A-FK-OR]/ig,'');`

Comment: Well, it's being sent to me from an external source, the message is. But I can do that.

Comment: It still returns [§aAnnouncement§r] §4test. Code: `console.log(message.replace(/§[0-9A-FK-OR]/ig,''));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83996/discussion-between-anubhava-and-brandon-palmer).